# Converting decimal (ASCII) number into 128bit binary (hex) values

Tags: python-3.x

I'm sure this should not be so difficult! I'm trying to use python to convert some IPv6 addresses that are stored as ASCII values (decimal) into binary (if not 128 bits in length, expand to 128 bit) and save to disk in little endian format.

I'm having all sorts of fun (not) trying to get this to work.

I've managed to get the ASCII values to convert to hex, and print the values to screen, however, if I try to use anything like struct.pack, I just get errors like: struct.error: argument out of range.

Coming from an assembly background, I really struggle with any kind of casting.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Using `socket.inet_pton` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/socket.html#socket.inet_pton)) to obtain from IPv6 string 128bit value:

```
import socket

packedIP = socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET6, '2001:db8::')

print(packedIP)
print('Length =', len(packedIP)*8)
```

Prints:

```
b' \x01\r\xb8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
Length = 128
```

EDIT:

```
import socket

import ipaddress
import struct

ip = int('281470698520832')

# to print IPv6 address
ipv6 = ipaddress.IPv6Address(ip)
print(str(ipv6))

# method 1.
packedIP = socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET6, str(ipv6))
print(packedIP)

# method 2.
max_int64 = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
packed = struct.pack('>QQ', (ip >> 64) & max_int64, ip & max_int64)
print(packed)
```

This prints IP address and byte array:

```
::ffff:100:100
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x01\x00\x01\x00'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x01\x00\x01\x00'
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that they are already in decimal format, like this:"281470698520832","281470698521599","CN","China"
"281470698521600","281470698522623","AU","Australia" and I'm trying to get them into raw little endian hexadecimal

Comment: Thank you very much, I now have something to play with!

Comment: Just tried this one: 42540488558116655331872044393019998208,  The output seems to be dropping the \x02 value. I expected it to be \x01\x20 Not b' \x01\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

Comment: @colinr '42540488558116655331872044393019998208' is address `2001:5::`. It has byte representation `b' \x01\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'`

Comment: Sure, but \x20 should also appear in that byte representation, but it's not there

Comment: @colinr The first space in `b' \x01\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'` is hex 20, but Python shows it as space (hex 20=ascii 32). To get hex string from integer: `'{:x}'.format(42540488558116655331872044393019998208)`   prints: `'20010005000000000000000000000000'`

Comment: Ah right, probably because hex 20 is the ascii character for space

Comment: As a followup to this, how would one go about outputting the same values in little endian?